# Calling an injected button from the content script to the background.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script, message-passing

I'm writing a chrome extension that injects a button into a youtube page. The button is created in my content script and injected into the page. My problem is that I have no idea how to build a click function for it, either in the content script or the background script.

my content script(the injected button):

```
 $("watch7-user-header").innerHTML+=
 '<div id="trans"> 
    <iframe name="iframe"></iframe>
    <span class="buttonGroup">
        <button id="download">
            <span class="buttonContent1">'+x+'</span> 
        </button>
        <button id="menu" class=" yt-uix-button  yt-uix-button-default" onclick="";return false;"> //this is the dropdown menu
            <span class="buttonContent1">
            </span>
            <ul id="stylelist" class="yt-uix-button-menu hid">'+o+S+"</ul>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>"
```

How would i call a click an event in the background script?

Comment: Did you try my proposed solution below ? Did it work for you ?

Comment: Unfortunatly no. Actually very confused as to why this would work.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. Are you trying to "click" the button programmaticaly or to register a listener for when it will be clicked by the user ? In the latter case, what should that callback do ?

Comment: Did you solve this issue ? If so consider posting it as an answer for the users that be coming here in the future looking for a similar answer. (If you are still lokking for a solution and need help, provide more details.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't "click" a button from the background page. If you wish to do it, you'll have to **[send a message](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#simple)** to the content script to do it for you.

From the content script, you can do it like this:

```
var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
});
document.querySelector('<yourElementSelector>').dispatchEvent(evt);
```

**UPDATE:**

If you are tryong to click a `<button>` element, you can simply do:

```
document.querySelector('<yourButtonSelector>').click();
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate little more?

Comment: What part is not clear ? You need to send a message from the background page to a content script and from the content script you need to execute some JavaScript code on the page (as shown above). There are plenty of resource (even here on SO) these steps in more detail.

Comment: It's a question from '13, but after reading it I think the question here was to make a click _handler_, not to click the button.